# Cannot create Bundle Identifier for iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I've developed an application with bundle identifier com.company.appname but I've always built it with my company team and auto-generated provisioning profile with no problem.
Now I need to build the application with the right customer's team but when I go on developer.apple.com to register the bundle identifier I receive the error:

```
An App ID with Identifier 'com.company.appname' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

Other information:
- In my company page on developer.apple.com there isn't any application identifier with "com.company.appname"
- In my company page on developer.apple.com I've only my provisioning debig profile
- In customer company page on developer.apple.com there isn't the bundle identifier registered, and if I try to register It the same error of XCode appears:

```
An App ID with Identifier 'com.company.appname' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

I guess that I've this error message because app ID is used from my company's "iOS team provisioning profile: *" that can correctly archive the application on XCode

EDIT: The only similar appID registered is "com.mycompany.appName" and the appID that I cannot create is "com.customercompany.appName". I think that bundle identifier is the complete name and not the name only.

Comment: Delete the wild card identifier that the app has automatically created.

Comment: @ElTomato Where? because I don't have the Wildcard on developer.apple.com

Comment: App ids are always unique across the entire apple landscape. So if I understand correctly you're using the app id already somewhere else. If that's the case you would need to create new one.

Comment: @JTea I've used it only to archive application on my macbook and distribute trough Diawi. On developer.apple.com or itunes connect there is no trace of my appID. And if There is one, I can delete It.

Comment: As far as I know you need to have an app ID registered when creating a an archive. So I don't quite get why there isn't a trace of it anywhere. Did you try to delete it then?

Comment: @JTea What am I suppose to delete if there isn't any trace of this BundleID on my accounts?

Comment: Just checked: it's possible to archive without having an app ID registered. So, then perhaps your app id has been registered on another account? The easiest way out is to use a different identifier :)

Comment: @JTea the only similar appID registered is "com.mycompany.appName" and the appID that I cannot create is "com.customercompany.appName"